# Aggregate with pipeline

Tags: mongodb, go

How should we accommodate bson.M for the pipeline while writing aggregate using golang, following is the code snippet of mongo.

```
db.orgclients.aggregate([
{$match: { clientStatus: { $in: [ 'ONB',D IS', 'HOSP' ] }, isActive:'Y'}},
{$project: {_id:0, tenantId:1, clientId:1},
{$lookup:
    {
        from: "org_contacts",


        let: { tenant_Id: "$tenantId", contact_RefId: "$contactReference.contactRefId"},
            pipeline:[
                {$match:
                    {$expr:
                        {$and:
                            [
                                { $eq: ["$tenantId", "$$tenant_Id"]},
                                { $in: ["$contactId", "$$contact_RefId"]}
                            ]
                        }                           
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "contactDetails"
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Any answer for the above request

Answer (score 1):

The input directly translates to Go objects:

```
aggregation:=[]bson.M{ 
  bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"clientStatus": bson.M{"$in": [ "ONB","D IS", "HOSP" ]},"isActive":"Y"}},
  bson.M{"$project": bson.M{"_id":0, "tenantId":1, "clientId":1}},
  ...
 }
```

If the input does not contain any variable references, you can initialize a query from a JSON-ified string constant once, and use it. As long as the input marshals to a valid mongodb expression, it will work. You have to property quote all map keys to convert this to JSON:

```
var aggregation interface{}

func init() {
  if err:=json.Unmarshal([]byte(`[
{"$match": { "clientStatus": { "$in": [ "ONB',"D IS", "HOSP" ] }, "isActive":"Y"}},
{"$project": {"_id":0, "tenantId":1, "clientId":1},
{"$lookup":
    {
        "from": "org_contacts",
        "let": { "tenant_Id": "$tenantId", "contact_RefId": "$contactReference.contactRefId"},
        "pipeline":[
            {"$match":
                {"$expr":
                    {"$and":
                        [
...                    
`),&aggregation);err!=nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}
```

Comment: During unmarshal, getting the error as follows .. panic: invalid character 'c' looking for beginning of object key string

Comment: You have to correctly quote all keys. No single quotes.

Comment: Also in order to use aggregation:=[]bson.M..., need clarification on how bson.M should be to accommodate with pipeline [ ] array. Ex: Is it like "pipleline": []bson.M{
  bson.M{
   "$match":....
}
}

Comment: You simply pass that to the aggregate function: `collection.Aggregate(ctx,aggregation)`

Comment: It is failing before calling collection.Aggregate. Observing panic error as 'nvalid character 'c' looking for beginning of object key string'. Also wanted to understand how to accommodate pipeline array within bson.M